# Insert com três tabelas no MySQL com PHP

Tags: mysql, sql

Para fins de estudos e testes, criei três tabelas no phpMyAdmin: **Pessoas**, **Contato**, **CredenciaisLogin**. As tabelas Contato e CredenciaisLogin estão relacionadas com Pessoas.

O objetivo é realizar a inserção de registros para as três tabelas.Para isso eu criei a seguinte query:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO pessoas VALUES (NULL, 'TESTE','teste@teste.com','2019-01-08','masc','TESTE'); 
INSERT INTO contato VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '33333333','Rua teste, 57','Catanduva','SP','18353-251');
INSERT INTO credenciaislogins VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'admin','admin');
COMMIT;
```

Onde o valor a ser retornado de `LAST_INSERT_ID()` seja o mesmo que foi inserido no insert anterior.

Porém, ao executar a query o seguinte erro é gerado

```
Comando SQL:

INSERT INTO contato VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '33333333','Rua teste, 57','Catanduva','SP','18353-251')
Mensagens do MySQL : Documentação

#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_testephp`.`contato`, CONSTRAINT `contato_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_PESSOA`) REFERENCES `pessoas` (`IDPESSOA`))
```

Como eu poderia fazer  o insert nestas três tabelas ao mesmo tempo?

Só lembrando que eu não estou preocupado neste momento com nenhum tipo de normalização das tabelas. Este projeto serva apenas para estudos.

Comment: `credenciaislogins` deve receber o id de  `pessoas` ou de `contato`?

Comment: No caso, a tabela credenciaislogins vai receber apenas de pessoas

Comment: Porque como o próprio nome diz, `LAST_INSERT_ID` retorna o último id adicionado, o que significa que no seu terceiros INSERT acaba usando o id criado pelo segundo. Tente armazenar o valor que deseja numa variável.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode resolver este problema de duas formas; a mais prática seria dar consultar o último `id` inserido na hora do *próximo* `insert`:

```
START TRANSACTION;
  INSERT INTO pessoas VALUES (NULL, 'TESTE','teste@teste.com','2019-01-08','masc','TESTE'); 
  INSERT INTO contato VALUES ((SELECT MAX(id) FROM pessoas), '33333333','Rua teste, 57','Catanduva','SP','18353-251');
  INSERT INTO credenciaislogins VALUES ((SELECT MAX(id) FROM pessoas), 'admin','admin');
COMMIT;
```

A segunda, mais performática já que não *refaz* consultas, seria criar uma variável para armazenar este valor:

```
START TRANSACTION;
  SET @id:= (SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM tabela1);
  INSERT INTO pessoas VALUES (@id, 'TESTE','teste@teste.com','2019-01-08','masc','TESTE'); 
  INSERT INTO contato VALUES (@id, '33333333','Rua teste, 57','Catanduva','SP','18353-251');
  INSERT INTO credenciaislogins VALUES (@id, 'admin','admin');
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Não seria melhor adicionar em uma variável PHP o valor do ID cadastrado da tabela pessoas com o `mysqli_insert_id()` e em seguida adicionar nas outras duas tabelas?

Comment: não acredito que isso tenha alguma diferença na performance ou na legibilidade do código, mas seria uma alternativa.